# Reading file on top of the previous one

Tags: python, file-io, io

I was wondering if it is perfectly safe to read one file onto another(before closing the buffer). Explanation for such a thing I would give is that the function open closes the buffer by itself automatically when using the same object.

Example code:

```
fr = open("asd.txt", "r")
text = fr.read()
fr.close

fr = open("asd2.txt", "r")
text = fr.read()
fr.close
...
```

Is this the same thing?

```
fr = open("asd.txt", "r")
text = fr.read()

fr = open("asd2.txt", "r")
text = fr.read()

fr.close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the second line is the same because *neither snippet properly closes files*.

You would have to **call** the `fr.close()` method to close the file object, without the `()` part the method is only referenced, not executed. So in both examples the `'asd.txt'` file object *is still open* when the second `open()` call is executed.

In CPython (the default Python implementation downloadable from Python.org) file objects are automatically closed when no longer referenced, so as soon as the second `open()` call returns and is assigned, the first open file is closed as the reference to the object is removed.

However, you should really use the file object as a context manager instead, using the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with):

```
with open("asd.txt", "r") as fr:
    text = fr.read()

with open("asd2.txt", "r") as fr:
    text = fr.read()
```

and more likely, use different variables names for `text` as one now replaces the other. File objects in a `with` statement are automatically closed when the block ends or an exception occurs in that block.

Comment: Sorry, the fr.close was a typo. I wanted actually fr.close() to write. So anyway is it adviced to write fr.close() after every read/write(before opening a new one)?

Comment: @Maxitj: Better to close the file as soon as you don't need it anymore. Using the `with` statement ensures that this always happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `text=open("test.txt").read()`, process the data and then open other files in the same manner. They will be closed as soon as the data is read.

A more pythonic way to work with files is to do this:

```
with open("test.txt") as your_file:
    text=your_file.read()
```

---

*Note*: when you want to close a file manually, you have to *call* the `close` function like this: `your_file.close()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as far as I remember, there's a function called `file`, not `File`, so this name can be used with no harm.

Comment: @ForceBru: still bad style to use a local with a capital letter, especially if that name also coincides to look like a built-in type.